# "The Hangar" chat room has been "frozen" for inactivity-- is this supposed to happen?

Tags: support, bug, moderators, chat

"The Hangar" chat room has been "frozen" for inactivity-- is this supposed to happen?

https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/12036

Basically I'm just trying to bring this to the mods' attention, or to the attention of whoever else might be able to unfreeze it.  Thanks.

If it was going to get unfrozen automatically at some future point when the system wanted to automatically post something there, that's fine, in that case no action need be taken.  I'm in no hurry to post anything there, just happened to notice that it was frozen.

Comment: I unfroze it FWIW and was coming back here to say pretty much what DL said

Answer (score 5):

It is not supposed to happen, but if there is a prolonged time of silence in the hangar, the stackexchange system will 'freeze' the room automatically.

Best way to prevent it is for us all to be more chatty in the hangar (and less chatty in the comments :-) )